# MVC View: Get value in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I need to add a value in a `ViewData` according to what option someone chooses in a dropdown:

```
<th class="centerAlign" style="font-weight: normal">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" *@ aria-expanded="true" style="height:28px">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Sort by</li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Selected</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Unselected</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </th>
```

So that

```
public ActionResult Index(bool? delivery_bool = null)
    {     

        ViewData["delivery_bool"] = delivery_bool;

        //more stuff

        return View();
    }
```

**Edit**

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page = null,
            string brand_name = null,
            string category_name = null,
            string language_name = null,
            string bco_name = null,
            int? material_number = null, 
            bool? derivation_bool = null,
            bool? artwork_bool = null,
            bool? delivery_bool = null,
            bool? export = null)
        {            
            ViewData["brand_name"] = brand_name;
            ViewData["category_name"] = category_name;
            ViewData["language_name"] = language_name;
            ViewData["bco_name"] = bco_name;
            ViewData["material_number"] = material_number;
            ViewData["derivation_bool"] = derivation_bool;
            ViewData["artwork_bool"] = artwork_bool;
            ViewData["delivery_bool"] = delivery_bool;
            ViewData["export"] = export;
            // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
            var pageNumber = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;

            //ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts = onePageOfProducts;

            // will only contain 12 products max because of the pageSize
            var query = db.EContent_MaterialsFinalViewWithBcos
                .Select(i => new Material
                {
                    Brand = i.Brand,
                    Category = i.Category,
                    Language = i.Language,
                    Bco = i.Bco,
                    MaterialCod = i.MaterialCod,
                    Derivation = i.Derivation,
                    Artwork = i.Artwork,
                    BcoDelivery = i.BcoDelivery,
                    MaterialId = i.MaterialId
                 });

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brand_name))
                query = query.Where(p => p.Brand.ToLower().Contains(brand_name.ToLower()));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(category_name))
                query = query.Where(p => p.Category.ToLower().Contains(category_name.ToLower()));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language_name))
                query = query.Where(p => p.Language.ToLower().Contains(language_name.ToLower()));

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bco_name))
            {
                if (bco_name.ToLower().Contains("no"))
                    query = query.Where(p => p.Bco == null);
                else
                    query = query.Where(p => p.Bco.ToLower().Contains(bco_name.ToLower()));
            }

            if(material_number != null)
                query = query.Where(p => p.MaterialCod == material_number);            

            IPagedList<Material> onePageOfProducts = query
                .OrderBy(i => i.MaterialCod)
                .ToPagedList<Material>(pageNumber, defaultPageSize);;

            return View("Index", onePageOfProducts);
        }
```

View:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc <!--import this so we get our HTML Helper-->

@model IPagedList<eContentMVC.Models.Material>

<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Materials", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
            </div>

            <div class="divid"></div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <div>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Reset filters", "Index",
                null,
                new { @class = "btn btn-success custom pull-left", @style = "color:white", @role = "button" }
                )
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- does nothing yet -->
            <button class="btn btn-default custom pull-right" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Export to Excel</button>

            </div>

        <div id="grid-list">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_AjaxMaterialList", Model); }
        </div>
    }
```

Partial View:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary filterable" style="padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="height:32px">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-size:14px">GDS eContent Master Data Service Tool</h3>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>//all the headers</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="font-weight: normal">
                    <input class="span2" type="text" name="brand_name"
                           value="@ViewData["brand_name"]" style="height:28px" placeholder="Search Brand for..."/></th>
                <th class="centerAlign" style="font-weight: normal">
                    <input class="span2" type="text" name="category_name"
                           value="@ViewData["category_name"]"  style="height:28px" placeholder="Search Category for..." />
                </th>

                //some headers like the upper input

                <th class="centerAlign" style="font-weight: normal">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" *@ aria-expanded="true" style="height:28px">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Sort by</li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Derived</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Not derived</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </th>

                //a bounch of dropdowns like the upper one
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <!--Labels are what the checkboxes are going to be searched for-->
                <!--To do: Use switch instead of if statements-->
                <tr>
                    <td class="centerAlign">@item.Brand.ToString()</td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">@item.Category.ToString()</td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">@item.Language.ToString()</td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">
                        @if (item.Bco == null)
                        {
                            <text>No Bco</text>}
                        else
                        {
                            <text>@item.Bco.ToString()</text> }
                    </td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">
                        @Html.ActionLink(@item.MaterialCod.ToString(),
                    "Details", "EContent_EcontentFields", new { id = item.MaterialId }, null)
                    </td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">
                        @if (item.Derivation != null && (bool)item.Derivation)
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" disabled /><label class="hidden">TrueYes</label>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" value="false" disabled /><label class="hidden">FalseNo</label>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">
                        @if (item.Artwork != null && (bool)item.Artwork)
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" disabled /><label class="hidden">TrueYes</label>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" value="false" disabled /><label class="hidden">FalseNo</label>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">
                        @if (item.BcoDelivery != null && (bool)item.BcoDelivery)
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="true" disabled /><label class="hidden">TrueYes</label>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" value="false" disabled /><label class="hidden">FalseNo</label>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td class="centerAlign">
                        <!-- To do: make this checkbox work -->
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@ViewData["export"]" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>    
</div>

<div class="centerAlign" style="padding: 0px; margin: -8px">
<!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Materials", new
    {
        brand_name = Request["brand_name"],
        category_name = Request["category_name"],        
        language_name = Request["language_name"],
        bco_name = Request["bco_name"],
        material_number = Request["material_number"],
        page
    }))
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to do it when someone changes value in dropdown - you should use js with ajax call. On the other hand you slould wrap it with form and submit.

Comment: Why do you need it in ViewData? You would have to do a full postback. Depending on what you are trying to do, you might be able to accomplish it using javascript.

Comment: @teo-van-kot Can you provide me a link to an example/article on any of them? I know nothing about both. The dropdown is already inside an form-submit so I think the js is the best option. I found nothing.

Comment: @br4d Hi, Brad. I need to filter a table by placing a filter on each column header. I already did that with text boxes for certain data. The thing is that some data is boolean so it's displayed in the form of check boxes. I need a dropdown to filter them. The `ViewData` is for when I retrieve the input to the controller method.

Comment: Well, we need to see all the related code in order to help you. You would need to post your controllers and views so we can see what and how you are currently doing the filtering.

Comment: I updated with all the code. What do you think?

Comment: you should just use a dropdownlist and be done with it.

Comment: @JamieD77 I give it a try, but dropdownlists looks ugly.

Comment: add bootstrap classes to make it blend.  `class="form-control"` usually works

Comment: @JamieD77 I made a new question for that topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274959/mvc-make-dropdownlist-helper-look-like-a-bootstrap-dropdown) because I need to elaborate.